# How arguments are passed into a cppFunction

Tags: rcpp

I'm puzzled as to how arguments are passed into a cppFunction when we use Rcpp. In particular, I wonder if someone can explain the result of the following code.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("void test(double &x, NumericVector y) {
    x = 2016;
    y[0] = 2016;
}")
a = 1L
b = 1L
c = 1
d = 1
test(a,b)
test(c,d)
cat(a,b,c,d) #this prints "1 1 1 2016"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated before in other areas, Rcpp establishes convenient classes around R's `SEXP` objects.

- For the first parameter, the `double` type does not have a default `SEXP` object. This is because within *R*, there is no such thing as a scalar. Thus, new memory is allocate making the `&` reference incompatible. Hence, the variable scope for the modification is limited to the function and there is never an update to the result. As a result, for both test cases, you will see  `1`.
- For the second case, there is a mismatch between object classes. Within the first call object supplied is of type `integer` due to the `L` appended on the end, which conflicts with the C++ function expected type of `numeric`. The issue is resolved once the `L` is dropped as the object is instantiated as a `numeric`. Therefore, an intermediary memory location does *not* need to be created that is of the correct type to receive the value. Hence, the modification in the second case is able to propagate back to *R*.

e.g.

```
a = 1L
class(a)
# "integer"
a = 1
class(a)
# "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks! So none of int, double, char has default SEXP object, right? BTW, is there any difference between passing the NumericVector by value and by reference?

Comment: @Gauchy10, correct. Also, the `NumericVector` is really a pointer and, thus, adding the `&` would just be visual sugar.