# Rcpp and R: pass by reference

Tags: r, pass-by-reference, rcpp, pass-by-value

Working with Rcpp and R I observed the following behaviour, which I do not understand at the moment. Consider the following simple function written in Rcpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix hadamard_product(NumericMatrix & X, NumericMatrix & Y){
   unsigned int ncol = X.ncol();
   unsigned int nrow = X.nrow();
   int counter = 0;
   for (unsigned int j=0; j<ncol; j++) {
     for (unsigned int i=0; i<nrow; i++)  {
        X[counter++] *= Y(i, j);
     }
   }
   return X;
}
```

This simply returns the component-wise product of two matrices. Now I know that the arguments to this function are passed by reference, i.e., calling

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol = 2)
N <- matrix(rnorm(4), ncol = 2)
M_copy <- M
hadamard_product(M, N)
```

will overwrite the original M. However, it also overwrites M_copy, which I do not understand. I thought that `M_copy <- M` makes a copy of the object M and saves it somewhere in the memory and not that this assignment points M_copy to M, which would be the behaviour when executing

```
x <- 1
y <- x
x <- 2
```

for example. This does not change y but only x.

So why does the behaviour above occur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How arguments are passed into a cppFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083921/how-arguments-are-passed-into-a-cppfunction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, R does not make a copy immediately, only if it is necessary, i.e., *copy-on-modify*:

```
x <- 1
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0000000009A57D78>"
y <- x
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0000000009A57D78>"
x <- 2
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<00000000099E9900>"
```

Since you modify M by reference outside R, R can't know that a copy is necessary. If you want to ensure a copy is made, you can use `data.table::copy`. Or avoid the side effect in your C++ code, e.g., make a deep copy there (by using `clone`).